# R: report the appearance sequence number of a value

Tags: r

So I have a list like below

```
 1. a
 2. a
 3. b
 4. b
 5. c
 6. c
 7. a
 8. a
```

Is it possible to get a list that number based on the sequence of each value in R:

```
 1. 1
 2. 2
 3. 1
 4. 2
 5. 1
 6. 2
 7. 3
 8. 4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ave`. Assuming your vector is called "x", try:

```
ave(x, x, FUN = seq_along)
# [1] "1" "2" "1" "2" "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

It's total overkill, but `getanID` from my "splitstackshape" package also does this:

```
library(splitstackshape)
getanID(as.data.table(x), "x")
#    x .id
# 1: a   1
# 2: a   2
# 3: b   1
# 4: b   2
# 5: c   1
# 6: c   2
# 7: a   3
# 8: a   4
```

#### Sample data

```
x <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "a", "a")
```

Comment: seq_along(x) would prevent that from becoming characters

Comment: @rawr I don't think that's true (it doesn't work with this sample). `ave()` returns the same class as the first parameter which is a character in this case. You do `unsplit(lapply(split(x, x), seq_along), x)` which is basically what `ave()` is doing but avoids the data type conversion.

Comment: @MrFlick, the easy approach would be to replace the first "x" with `rep(1, length(x))`, I guess... or use my `getanID` function :-)

Comment: Oh, I see, rawr was suggesting `ave(seq_along(x), x, FUN = seq_along)`. Got it.